multiple incarnations of "same" variable in JS local scope - chrome debugger
Have a look a this loop in javascript, and what is showing in the debugger. for some reason there are 4 occurrences of the item variable, however there should be only 1 (unless it seems I'm missing something).
You can see on the right side filteredAttributes.values is an array with 1 object. It gets sorted and mapped, the first time into the inner loop, when setting a breakpoint reveals unexpected values.
What is going on here?!

{filteredAttribute?.values.length > 0 ? (
  filteredAttribute?.values
    .sort((a, b) => a.fmOrder - b.fmOrder)
    .map((item, i) => {


Images of code make debugging very difficult; please [edit] your question to include the relevant code as text.

I've added the relevant code as text

Looks like a bug to me. To be certain of the true value, evaluate item in the console while paused at that breakpoint.

Given you're using JSX, I guess it's an issue with sourcemaps; though I see no reason for complicated mappings in this code (where different variables in the compiled code get mapped to the same source name).

I just tried Firefox, it only shows the one variable. Crazy, I haven't had to use Firefox in forever! I will do some more testing and potentially open a bug with Chrome. I've seen similar behavior recently on a different Next js project on a different machine with Chrome.
